# Android adapter layout infalter error

Tags: android

I have an adapter, I want to inflate a view but I can't.

This is my class code:

```
private static class RandomsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Randoms randoms;
    private RandomsAdapter(Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
    }
    public void updateRandoms(Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Random getItem(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars,parent,false);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error for this line: `convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars,parent,false);`

Error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getLayoutInflater() from the type Activity`

How can I resolve it?

Comment: [If you're not within an Activity, you need to get a layout inflater from some other Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803771/call-to-getlayoutinflater-in-places-not-in-activity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass Activity Context to your adapter. In the constructor:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RandomsAdapter(Context context, Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

Then you inflate layout as:

```
convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.random_bars,parent,false);
```

Comment: Now I am getting error for this line:ListAdapter randomsAdapter=new RandomsAdapter(randoms); Error:The constructor MainActivity.RandomsAdapter(MainActivity.Randoms) is undefined I think I have to pass context but how ?

Comment: @SerkaySarıman `ListAdapter randomsAdapter=new RandomsAdapter(this, randoms);` or `ListAdapter randomsAdapter=new RandomsAdapter(MainActivity.this, randoms);`

Answer (score 0):

you need Context inside this class& add it to constructor as

```
private RandomsAdapter(Randoms randoms, Context context) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        this.mContext = context;
}
```

or remove "static" word from RandomsAdapter class definition