# Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-listview

I get this exception `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference` but I am able to find the reason.

In the mainactivity I create a ListView element, the structure is:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
/>
```

And I create a custom Adapter class for the listview,

```
class ListItem
{
    public String shortDescription;
    public String type;
    public String time;
    public int imageId;

    public ListItem(String sd, String type, String time, Integer imageId)
    {
        this.shortDescription = sd;
        this.type = type;
        this.time = time;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}


public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<Object>{

    private Activity context;
    private ListItem listItem[];

    public CustomList(Activity context, ListItem li[]){
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, li);
        this.listItem = li;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        TextView sd = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.sd);
        TextView type = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        TextView days = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.days);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        sd.setText(listItem[position].shortDescription);
        type.setText(listItem[position].type);
        days.setText(listItem[position].time);
        icon.setImageResource(listItem[position].imageId);
        return rowView;
    }
```

And I call this in my MainActivity class,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ListItem listItem[] = new ListItem[2];
    Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.ic_launcher};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItem[0] = new ListItem("test", "test", "test", imageId[0]);
        listItem[1] = new ListItem("test1", "test1", "test1", imageId[0]);

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, listItem);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I get the exception in the custom Adapter class , at **LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();**. But the variable **context** is initialized in the constructor call itself. Why does it throw an Exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to getLayoutInflater() in places not in activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803771/call-to-getlayoutinflater-in-places-not-in-activity)

Comment: Please always provide **exact** error messages. Copy it from your LogCat and paste it inside a codeblock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`context` is `null`. forget to initialize.do it as:

```
public CustomList(Activity context, ListItem li[]){
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, li);
        this.listItem = li;
        this.context=context; //<< initialize here
    }
```

Comment: Does it need Activity Context or it is possible to declare Context context and pass getContext() from fragment?