# Can't use getLayoutInflater() in Android

Tags: android

If my code `extends AppCompatActivity`:

```
View uploadProgressView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_upload_progress, null);
UploadProgressViewHolder viewHolder = new UploadProgressViewHolder(uploadProgressView, filename);
```

I can use `getLayoutInflater()` but when I change to `extends Services` it is not working.

I was research on `Stackoverflow` [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803771/call-to-getlayoutinflater-in-places-not-in-activity) and receive answer and change to:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View uploadProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_upload_progress, null);
UploadProgressViewHolder viewHolder = new UploadProgressViewHolder(uploadProgressView, filename);
```

But it is not working, how to use `getLayoutInflater()`?

This throw exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

CallRecordService.addUploadToList(CallRecordService.java:167)
Error at first line `LayoutInflater inflater = ......`

```
Context context;
private void addUploadToList(String uploadID, String filename) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View uploadProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_upload_progress, null);
    UploadProgressViewHolder viewHolder = new UploadProgressViewHolder(uploadProgressView, filename);
    viewHolder.uploadId = uploadID;
    container.addView(viewHolder.itemView, 0);
    uploadProgressHolders.put(uploadID, viewHolder);
}
```

Comment: Why is the second piece of code not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it is not working"? Is it a compile error? Or you are getting null reference?

Comment: *I change to extends Services it is not working*, that's the expected behaviour. Service has not UI

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE , I was updating my question.

Comment: Your `context` variable is not initialized.

Comment: Your context is not initialized. Does this code resides in a class that extends  Service?

Comment: I can't initialize with: `Context context = new Context();` How to initialized context?

Comment: @leo.Ren is this code written in a `Service`? If yes, you can directly use `getSystemService()` without a context.

Comment: @KNeerajLal , I write services to record all call. I changed my code to: `View uploadProgressView = getSystemService().inflate(R.layout.view_upload_progress, null);` but seem don't have inflate in getSystemServices()  and is not working.

Comment: @leo.Ren What is the error?

Comment: @KNeerajLal : I receive error from logcat:
`error: no suitable method found for getSystemService()
method ContextWrapper.getSystemService(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Context.getSystemService(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)`

Comment: @leo.Ren See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```

This is because, `Service` is a `Context`. Service extends `ContextWrapper` which extends `Context`. You can also use 'this' keyword in the service.

Comment: Thanks. It pass line inflater but throw exception in this rows: `container.addView(viewHolder.itemView, 0);` error like this: `CallRecordService.addUploadToList(CallRecordService.java:173)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Layout to `WindowManager` after inflating view using `LayoutManager`.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(view, getLayoutParams());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your in a class that extends `Service` you can use

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

or

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

Both are valid because a `Service` is a `Context`